# Automatically generated git commit message with regex

Tags: git

I'd like to set up a git alias that would execute git commit with auto generated message like this:

"Affected files: [...], [...], [...]."

Whereby [...] is a regex match against the respective file name.

- I want to use it only when updating existing files (no additions, deletions).
- If regex part is too clunky, I'd be fine with full file names.
- Having inline comma separated list (as opposed to multi-line) is critical requirement.
- Not having to touch message in editor is critical requirement.

I am using git bash on windows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve doing that? The information which files are updated is already contained in the commit itself. Duplicating it into the message seems to be redundant. Maybe what you want to achieve can also be solved using the information from the commit?

Comment: Such a commit message is not especially useful, since you can trivially generate this from the repository. Simply run `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r --diff-filter=M <commit-id>` (pipe through some small script to make them comma-separated instead of one-per-line).

Comment: Use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazycommit-cli) package [lazycommit](https://codeberg.org/fftcc/lazycommit-cli)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing a `commit-msg` hook (read: script) in the `.git/hooks` directory of your project.

Running `git diff --cached --name-status` should give you all the information about the [about to be] committed files, which you can parse with `awk` (or a bunch of `grep`s and `cut`s) and then organize it with `paste`. Putting it all together, your script should look more or less like this:

```sh
modified_files=`git diff --cached --name-status | awk '$1 == "M" { print $2 }'| paste -d', ' -s`
if test "" != "$modified_files"
then
    echo "Affected files: $modified_files" >> $1
fi
```

Note that by default this will still open the editor window, but you could work around it by just running `git commit -m ""` (or some other message) when you commit.

**Note:**
I tested this with `/bin/sh` on my Fedora 24 laptop, and it works fine. I'm not sure git bash on Windows has all of these capabilities, but at the very least it should have equivalent facilities.

**EDIT:**
As @torek suggested in the comments, this can be simplified using the `--diff-filter` option:

```sh
modified_files=`git diff --cached --diff-filter='M' --name-only | paste -d', ' -s`
if test "" != "$modified_files"
then
    echo "Affected files: $modified_files" >> $1
fi
```

Comment: To simplify the diff filtering, use `--diff-filter=M` which retains only those for which the status is `M`.  Then you can use `--name-only` and omit the `awk` entirely.

Comment: @torek Good idea, thanks! I've edited it into my answer (with the proper attribution, of course).

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik. I slightly modified  the original awk version. This did the trick for me:

modified_files=`git diff --cached --name-status | awk '{ match($2, "_([0-9]{4})_", a); print a[1]}' | paste -d', ' -s`
if test "" != "$modified_files"
then
    echo "Affected files: $modified_files" >> $1
fi

Comment: Two remaining questions. 1. Is there a way how to tell 'paste' command to really use 2 character delimiter (comma + space)? 2. The hook now kicks in always when I do commit in my project, which is OK in 90%. But every now and then I'd like to do custom commit message. What would be the most effective way of circumventing this hook?

Answer (score 0):

Needs zsh, GNU sed, ripgrep and NightMachinary/prefixer.

```
trimsed () {
    gsed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
}
git-commitmsg () {
    local msg="$(git -c color.status=false status | command rg --color never -e 'deleted:' -e 'modified:' -e 'new file:'| trimsed | prefixer --skip-empty -o '; ')"
    print -r -- "${msg:-.}"
}
```